# Why is Fragment.addToBackStack() causing the Back button to do nothing?

Tags: android

1. Activity 1 is visible. Press a button, and Activity 2 opens.
2. Activity 2 adds fragment A to itself (and back stack) and it displays fine
3. Pressing a button within the fragment transitions to another fragment, B
4. Press Back. Nothing happens. Huh? The Back press is seemingly absorbed and not acted upon, the display remains the same.
5. Press Back a second time, it reverts to the Activity 1, as expected.

Why is my fragment not being shown in step 4? I've added the fragment to the back stack, so why (when the Back button seems aware of its existence) does it not show the fragment?

Here's the code I'm using in Activity 2 to open Fragment A.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_profile_edit);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.add(android.R.id.content, new MyFragment());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

And here's the code to open Fragment B

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    transaction.add(android.R.id.content, new MyOtherFragment());
    transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried `transaction.replace(...)` instead of `transaction.add(...)`? That should work. I'm guessing because if you're just adding a fragment over another, it doesn't see transaction as wanting to go back fro Fragment A.

**EDIT** 
The actual answer for the question is below in the comments: addToBackStack() should be used on the fragment which is *replacing*, not the one being replaced.

Comment: This doesn't help. If I use replace initially (instead of add) there's no fragment to replace, so I'd expect it to behave the same. If I were to use replace to show fragment B, it'd overwrite the one I want people to use Back to revert to, so that wouldn't help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by frame. I've added the code that opens the second fragment.

Comment: use addToBackStack(null) on the transaction to add B, not to add A. I know that's slightly counterintuitive, but that should work

Comment: I'm not sure my brain was switched on. You're absolutely right. Thanks.

Comment: i had this problem. but I caused it! i overrided onResume on my first fragment, so it "auto-enables" some staff on second fragment. On XL/Large devices result was what i wanted. on regular layout devices(smartphones), caused back button not to work, because it went immediately  to second fragment. So modified onResume in first fragment, not to act this way, IF its a regular layout. Its confusing i know, but somebody who did the same, this may help! :)